# The agent is stopped or has been stopped, no additional provocateurs can be created

Tags: masstransit

Every once in a while, I start to see the following exception. I'm not sure how to fix it, or why does the app think it's stopping. The only way to fix it is to restart the app. What is the best practice for this error? What is the reason for this error?

```
System.OperationCanceledException: The agent is stopped or has been stopped, no additional provocateurs can be created.
at GreenPipes.Caching.Internals.NodeValueFactory`1.<CreateValue>d__7.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at offset 12
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) at offset 38
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) at offset 46
at GreenPipes.Caching.Internals.NodeTracker`1.<AddNode>d__38.MoveNext()
```

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce this, despite several people saying it has happened to them. Some have fixed it by doing something with container lifecycle changes around `IBus` but without being able to cause it myself, I can't really comment.

Comment: But the app is running by itself. If you can just tell me which property handles this, and how i can switch it, then perhaps I can find a solution. Do you have links to other people asking the same question. perhaps it would be helpful to read them

Comment: @Ahmet Have you solved this issue?

Comment: Not really. I just keep restarting if it happens. But it happens only during deploys as far as I see.

Comment: I've seen this too and I badly need to find a solution on how to fix this!

Comment: it happens here as well

Comment: Same problem. The bus is starting in OWN application under IIS. The app was initially launched with incorrect RabbitMQ settings. After a while, the configuration was fixed, but the problem remained. Recycle helps.